# Can I transfer funds to another blizzard account?

Tags: hearthstone

OK well I messed up.  I have two blizzard accounts and I wanted to buy blackrock for the account I actually use. So I click on the button that takes me to the website so I can add funds. What I didn't realize, is that it took me to the site where I was already logged into the wrong account and I added the funds.  Is this irreversible? Am I out the 25 bones?

Comment: For fear of being wrong, I won't put this in an asnwer, but my thoughts are:
NO, you cannot do this. Blizzard has strict policies about "B.net Funds" and they cannot be taken out of the account ever. However, this isn't necessarily taking the funds out of an account since they will be going into a different one, but based on policies and bank transaction fees, I doubt Blizzard would ever allow this, try contacting customer service and ask.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. [Contact Blizzard Customer Support](https://us.battle.net/support/en/help/), explain your issue, and they may be able to assist you. It's not likely they will be willing or legally able to do this unless both accounts are **already in the same name** and **have the same payment information**. If they cannot, your only option would be to initiate a chargeback through your bank, and that comes with its own set of issues.

Comment: I believe if you do a chargeback they will permanently suspend the account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this by yourself, you will have to contact blizzard support for hearthstone. They are not obligated to fix this issue but should be willing to as long as you can prove that you own both accounts. As a word of advice do not play on the account, it will give your case a better chance. Do this as soon as possible too.

If you do decide to charge back the account, that hearthstone account will be banned.